# Lag in financial trading vs Group Delay in signal processing

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, group-delay

I'm a newbie to Signal Processing - and so I'm providing a "background" and a "question" section separately.

---

***Background:***

Suppose I have a **linear** filter (w.r.t. given as

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t + \lambda (x_t - \theta_t)$

In Financial Trading, such a filter is often called an exponential moving average, often applied to both prices (to get smoothened prices) and to square of price returns (to get "EWMA" volatility). By conventional definition:

$\lambda =  \frac{2}{n+1}$, where $n$ is periods (example $20$-day EWMA volatility).

Usually, a lot of folks in Financial Trading define **"lag"** as the expected value of the filter, when $x_u$ is replace by $t-u$. For instance, the above filter can also be written as

$\theta_{t+1} = \lambda (x_t+(1-\lambda) x_{t-1}+ (1-\lambda)^2 x_{t-2}+ ...)$

To get the **"lag"** of this filter in Financial Trading, we write

$L(\theta) = \lambda (0+(1-\lambda) 1+ (1-\lambda)^2 2+ ...)$

which gives

$L(\theta) = (1-\lambda)/\lambda = \frac{n-1}{2}$.

---

***Question:***

Now suppose I have a filter that is non-linear in $\theta$. Example, suppose it is

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t + \lambda \frac{1}{2}(x_{t}^2 e^{2\theta_t}-1)$

I have no idea what would be the equivalent of a **lag** here. Some folks told me that the definition of **lag** in Financial Trading is equivalent to the **group delay** (or may be **phase delay**) in Signal Processing.

(1) I looked up the definition of **group delay** and **phase delay** (e.g. on Wiki), but I couldn't exactly relate them to the definition of **lag** in Financial Trading. For the linear example:

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t + \lambda (x_t - \theta_t)$

what would be the **group delay** (or may be **phase delay** if that's more equivalent)?

(2) For the non-linear example:

$\theta_{t+1} = \theta_t + \lambda \frac{1}{2}(x_{t}^2 e^{2\theta_t}-1)$

what would be the **group delay** / **phase delay** or the equivalent of **lag** as applied to the linear filters in Financial Trading?

Comment: the Wiki article is a bit of a mess.  some of that i am to blame.  i should revisit it and maybe fix it up a bit.  your *"exponential moving average"* filter is what we in DSP would call a "1-pole filter".  $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is the "time constant" and i think, to relate that to the correct half-life, you need a $\log(2)$ in there somewhere, so i don't think your expression is correct.  the group delay of a 1-pole filter is the same as its time constant, IIRC.  i dunno what the relationship is with the phase delay, but i can try to figger it out.

Comment: I removed the referance to "half-life" to remove confusion and replaced it as $n$ is a period (e.g. $20$-day EWMA volatility). The rest of the background/question should be fine

Comment: well, a one pole filter is pretty simple and well-defined.  but the mathematical semantics that you financial guys like using leaves some to be desired.  i'll get back to this tonight if no one else answers.  also, i need to correct myself.  the one-pole filter is not a linear-phase filter, so its group delay and phase delay are not constant.  but, if the impulse response is $A \cdot e^{-\lambda t}$ (which i think it is), then the time-constant $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is the same as both the group delay and the phase delay at a frequency of 0 (at DC).

Answer (score 2):

i'm gonna work on this using the EE DSP notation i think is most conventional in the EE DSP field.  your exponentially-decaying 1-pole filter has this simple **difference equation**:

$$ y[n] = (1-p) \, x[n] \ + \ p \, y[n-1] $$

turns out (as we shall see below) that $p$ is the pole.  applying the Z transform gets you

$$ Y(z) = (1-p) \, X(z) \ + \ p \, z^{-1}Y(z) $$

from which we can solve for the **transfer function**:

$$ H(z) \triangleq \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{1-p}{1-p\,z^{-1}} = (1-p)\frac{z}{z-p} $$

so there is a zero at $z=0$ and a (real) pole at $z=p$.  the zero would go away if we took our input from $x[n-1]$ instead of $x[n]$ which would create a pole at $z=0$ and cancel the zero, but all that does is introduce another sample period of delay.  i don't think you wanna do that.

the (Kronecker) **impulse response** is

$$ \begin{align}
h[n] & = (1-p) p^n u[n] \\
& = (1-p) e^{\log(p) \, n} u[n] \\
& = (1-p) e^{n / \tau} u[n] \\
\end{align} $$

where u[n] is the Heaviside unit step function

$$ u[n] \triangleq
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }n \ge 0 \\
0, & \text{if }n < 0
\end{cases} $$

and $\tau$ is the *"time constant"* of the decaying exponential.  in order for the filter to be stable, the exponential must be decaying which means that $\tau > 0$, $\log(p) < 0$, and $0 < p < 1$

okay, so now the **complex frequency response** of $H(z)$ is

$$ \begin{align}
H(z)\bigg|_{z=e^{j\omega}} = H(e^{j\omega}) & = \frac{1-p}{1-p \, e^{-j\omega}} \\
& = \frac{1-p}{1-p \, \left(\cos(\omega) + j\sin(\omega) \right)} \\
\end{align} $$

the **magnitude response** is

$$ \begin{align}
|H(e^{j\omega})| & = \left|\frac{1-p}{1-p \, e^{-j\omega}} \right| \\
& = \left| \frac{1-p}{1-p \, \left(\cos(\omega) + j\sin(\omega) \right)} \right| \\
& = \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{ (1-p\cos(\omega))^2 + (p\sin(\omega))^2 }} \\
& = \frac{1-p}{\sqrt{ 1 + p^2 - 2 p \cos(\omega) }} \\
\end{align} $$

this is pretty familiar.  less oft observed is the **phase response**

$$ \begin{align}
\phi(\omega) \triangleq \arg \{ H(e^{j\omega}) \} & = \arg \left\{ \frac{1-p}{1-p \, e^{-j\omega}} \right\} \\
& = \arg \{ 1-p \} - \arg \{1-p \, e^{-j\omega} \} \\
& = 0 - \arg \{1-p (\cos(\omega) + j \sin(\omega)) \} \\
& = - \arctan \left( \frac{p \sin(\omega)}{1-p \cos(\omega)} \right) \\
\end{align} $$

the **phase delay** is

$$ \tau_\phi(\omega) \triangleq -\frac{\phi(\omega)}{\omega} $$

and the **group delay** is

$$ \tau_g(\omega) \triangleq -\frac{d\phi(\omega)}{d\omega} $$

gotta go.  i'll post this now and finish it later.  perhaps someone else wants to finish it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found my answer. **Lag** as defined by Financial Traders would be equal to $-\frac{dH(z)}{dz}\bigg|_{z=1}$ whose solution matches with a few filters that I tried.